# how to exclude control from a WinForm.Opacity in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form that i set it's Opacity as 50% like this:

```
this.Opacity = 0.5D; <--this==Form
```

My problem is that everything that on the form is with an Opacity of 50%

I have two buttons on the form and I want them without Opacity.

**I know that `this.Opacity` included all Controls and for some reason the graphics too**

My question is, How to Exclude the Opacity of the controls?

Example Image:
[image: example 2]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to reduce the form's opacity? Or you only want to bring in a dim effect? If it's the latter, there are crude hacks to highlight your controls.

Comment: Trasparency key is you problem solver : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Control` doesn't have `Opacity` property and plus that, most of the controls doesn't support transparent colors, then a working solution can be this:

1. Create a `Form` called `MainForm` and place all the controls you're going to be excluded.

   1.1 Set both of `BackColor` and `TransparencyKey` properties  of `MainForm` to the same color, e.g `Color.Red`
2. Create another form named `TransparentForm` and place all controls that must become transparent. Set `ShowInTaskbar` property to `False`.
3. In the `MainForm` `Load` event show the `TransparentForm` and send it to back.

   ```
   private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       TransparentForm form = new TransparentForm();
       form.Opacity = 0.5D;
       form.Show();
       form.SendToBack(); 
   }
   ```

   [image]

The position of controls in both form must be such that, when combined, it shows the proper user interface.

Comment: That sound like a good direction. I will try it and comment back! Thanks!

Comment: Rather than sending all control that should be transparent to another form, isn't it better just to send the controls that shouldn't be transparent and not `SendToBack`?

Comment: It is the right idea, but you'll need to at least use Show(owner) to keep one on top of the other.  And the top one should use the TransparencyKey property, the bottom one should use the Opacity property.

Answer (score -1):

Crate a C# project and add 3 forms named

1. MAIN
2. BACKGOUND
3. Child

and add the following code for "MAIN" form  load event;

```
private void MAIN_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Child frm1 = new  Child();
     BACKGOUND frm2 = new BACKGOUND();
     frm2 .WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;      

     frm2.Opacity = 0.5;
     frm2.Show();

     frm1.ShowDialog();
     frm2.Close();
}
```