# How to change opacity of Form window without changing opacity of text

Tags: c#, transparency, opacity

I'm trying to recreate a Kali-Linux DOS window, just for fun and have my own custom commands in it.

I'm making a form which is a 70% visible form.
Problem is, I tried putting the opacity of form to 70% but it made it ALL 70% visible instead. 
Putting in a picturebox and changing opacity of it didn't help either since it only shows the application instead of the background of my computer.

I know I could have done console application for this, but there is no appearance customization.

Comment: One thing you can do *if you want the form to be 100% transparent* is to use the `TransparencyKey` instead of  `Opacity`. If that doesn't suit your needs, you might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13136159/4934172).

Comment: It kind of worked, but now it is invisible. Is it possible to choose transparency percent?

Comment: If you set the `TransparencyKey` to match the Form BackColor, it will be 100% transparent. There's no way to control the percentage. Otherwise you would have to use the other way as described in the answer I referred to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply not possible in WinForms. A partially transparent form cannot have opaque controls. Some people might recommend using two forms, one fully transparent with opaque controls over another partially transparent, but I won't go into that.

The opacity of the form will change all controls in the form

Follow Genius Brain alternate example. That is the only way to achieve partial transparency, and so on.

Comment: My form 1 will be invisible, then I make a form 2 which has a opacity of 70% which follows and is stuck to form 1.

Comment: exactly but as far as coding all of that its something I don't do very often. I do have some forms that are transparent and borderless, and I program all my buttons for maximize and minimize as well as exit. Then I do form events. I just happen to be a System.Speech expert but no one has any speech questions. So I figured I would answer this one. Also be advised that your controls such as buttons will automatically highlight and that is one thing I don't like so I use labels with a click event for the Maximize, minimize and exit, instead of using buttons.

Comment: Maybe I'm not supposed to do what I want. But I want it my way, and I'll search it up till I find what I'm looking for.