# How do I show what is behind a windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to show what is behind a windows form. I want to minimize the form on startup, take a screenshot of the things behind the form, and set the screen shot as the background image.

I have already tried to following code:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
var X1 = this.PointToScreen(panel1.Location).X;
var Y1 = this.PointToScreen(panel1.Location).X;

var X2 = this.PointToScreen(panel2.Location).X;
var Y2 = this.PointToScreen(panel2.Location).X;

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
g.CopyFromScreen(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, bitmap.Size);
this.BackgroundImage = bitmap;

this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

panel 1 is located on the top left corner of the form and panel 2 is located on the bottom left corner of the form

When I run this code however, the background image does not show.

I am using windows forms in c#

Comment: Do you actually want to set the background image of the form for some reason or you're just trying to show what's behind it? Did you consider using the [`Opacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.opacity) property (which will make the form (semi)transparent)?

Comment: You might want to move the following code line `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;` to right before `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed If I set the opacity property, the controls would not be fully opaque

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have tried moving ```this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;``` and it still does not work

Comment: ... And I'm guessing that didn't help?

Comment: @Apollo199999999 Check my answer below. It shows how to change the BackgroundImage of the form and also refers to an answer that explains how you can use the `Opacity` property and still keep the controls visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually need to set the background image of your form, you may add the following code in your form's `Load` event handler:

```
var rect = this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

//this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;    // If you use the Load event,
                                                   // you don't really need this line.
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Location, Point.Empty, bitmap.Size);
}
this.BackgroundImage = bitmap;
//this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;       // Same here.
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, if you just want to show whatever is behind your form, the [`Form.Opacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.opacity) property could be useful. It can help you make the form semi-transparent:

```
this.Opacity = 0.5;
```

And you can even make the form semi-transparent (or even fully transparent) except for its controls as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13136159/4934172).

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and let you know how it goes